# Unable to debug the C# code to call API for google analytics data GA4

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-analytics-4

I am trying to debug the below code using the SSIS script task but every time it is getting failed with the generic error  "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.". I am using .net framework 4.5 And have disabled the Java runtime from the toolbox, but not sure why it is failing as the build is successful, I can see that at every block where it is "Authenticate and create the service" only it fails. The code is similar to the below :

```
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta;
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      // Google Analytics 4 property ID.
      string propertyId = "GA4_PROPERTY_ID";

      // Credential Path
      string credentialsPath =
          @"C:\\Users\XXXX\CSharpLibs\GoogleAnalytics4.json";

      // Authenticate and create the service.
      GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialsPath);
      AnalyticsDataService service =
          new AnalyticsDataService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Google Analytics 4",
          });

      // Construct the request.
      RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest() {

        Property = $"properties/{propertyId}",

        DateRanges = { new DateRange() { StartDate = "2023-05-15",
                                         EndDate = "2023-05-15" } },

        Dimensions = { new Dimension() { Name = "date" } },

        Metrics = { new Metric() { Name = "sessions" } }

      };

      // Execute request.
      RunReportResponse response =
          service.Properties.RunReport(request, propertyId).Execute();

      // Print the results.
      Console.WriteLine("Report result:");
      foreach (Row row in response.Rows) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row.DimensionValues[0].Value,
                          row.MetricValues[0].Value);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

}
```